# Separar um array de JSON em colunas e linhas

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Estou recebendo um array de JSON no back end dessa forma :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
{
    "idDistrito": "23",
    "nome": "rere",
    "codigoDne": "154545",
    "cns": "565665",
    "entidade": {
        "idEntidade": "1",
        "nome": "Entidade 01"
    },        
    "emissaoProfissional": "07/11/2017"

}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para separa os atributos das variáveis para montar uma tabela sendo que os atributos seriam coluna e as variáveis seriam linhas.

Comment: Se entendi direito você quer montar uma tabela através do resultado de um `Json` ?

Comment: @Marconi sim essa é a idéia.

Comment: Tem como postar seu Json(ou pelo ao menos parte dele) no código em vez da imagem?

Comment: sim, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi editei a pergunta e incluí o código `json`

Comment: acho que ele quis dizer o código que gera o Json

Comment: A pergunta é: estrutura de todos os objetos dentro do *array* será a mesma ou pode diferenciar? quero dizer, se tem objeto que pode vir com `nome` e outros não...

Comment: @LucasCosta no caso dessa página alguns itens não são obrigatórios, por exemplo o `codigoDne` poderá vim vazio. mas o Atributo vai vim.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke Você está usando AngularJs?

Comment: Uso o angularJs sim.. Mas algumas funções prefiro JavaScript

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke acho que o que precisa está na resposta abaixo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o método `.each()`, ele foi projetado para tornar as construções de loop do DOM concisas e menos propensas a erros. Quando chamado iterar sobre os elementos DOM que fazem parte do objeto `jQuery`. Cada vez que o retorno de chamada é executado, é passada a iteração de loop atual, começando de 0.

```
var html_ = "";
$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
    html_ += "<tr>";
    html_ += "<td>"+value.idDistrito+"</td>";
    html_ += "<td>"+value.nome+"</td>";
    html_ += "<td>"+value.campox+"</td>";
    html_ += "<td>"+value.campoy+"</td>";
    html_ += "</td></tr>";
    // ou ao inves da variavel html pode usar o 
    $("#tabela").last().append("<tr><td>"+value.idDistrito+"</td><td>"+value.nome+"</td><td>"+value.campox+"</td>td>"+value.campoy+"</td></td></tr>");
});
$("#tabela").html(html_);
```

Comment: Por que você declara `html` e usa `html_`?

Comment: Ops erro meu, obrigado por notar, editei ja